# Procedural Materials On Fluid Simulations

Tags: shaders, fluid-simulation, procedural

Been struggling with this for a while. I've made a procedural lava shader and I want to put it on a fluid sim. The problem is, all the mapping methods I've tried make the fluid travel through noise textures in 3D space rather than the noise flowing with the lava.

Is there something like the particle info node that I should be using the apply the texture to the fluid sim as it's generated?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: This is an interesting problem as far as I know there is no simple way to correctly map a texture on a fluid because it can't really be unwrapped, and there probaby isn't any deterministic solution to solve the issue. If the lava moves primarily in one direction you could try mapping it to object based texture coordinates with an empty moving roughly at the same speed as the lava

Comment: I saw a tutorial doing this but unfortunately my simulation is more complicated and goes in multiple directions and it's also a continous flow. I think the issue is the noise texture node rather than the mapping. Generated seems to give me a good result but the noise seems to have it's own co-ordinates in 3D space that the fluid is moving through which is overwriting my shader overall.

Comment: Speaking to some guys at work, in Houdini you can use particles doing the same movements and assign them colours. Then the mesh finds the closest vertex in proximity to the particle and assings it that colour. Any ideas if Blender has a similar system?

Comment: I'm not aware of any, as far as I know, perhaps [Animation Nodes](https://github.com/JacquesLucke/animation_nodes) can do something equivalent. Not sure, never used it myself.